# How to concatenate and Alter/Update table

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to insert the next highest number into the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096642/how-to-insert-the-next-highest-number-into-the-database)

I am using MYSQL

I have a column known as TeacherId which is auto incremented and goes like this:

```
TeacherId

1
2
3
4
```

What I want to do is add the letter 'T' in front of the numbers so it becomes:

```
TeacherId

T1
T2
T3
T4
```

How can I update or alter table to do this?

Below is my attempt but it did not work:

```
UPDATE Teacher SET TeacherId = CONCAT('T',TeacherId)
```

Comment: If it's auto increment then its a numeric field. You can't put a `'T'` in a numeric field.  You need to create a new field, one that's `VARCHAR(8)` for example.  And put your concatenated results in there.  *[Also, please supply the error messages to queries that don't work.  They're very illuminating.]*

Comment: If your column is set as AUTO_INCREMENT it has to be an integer, in which case you can't add letters to it.

Comment: Why on earth would you need to store the T? Add the T when you query / display the data. What else could anything in a Teachers table be but a T?

Comment: OK well, if I change it to varchar then will my statement at the bottom work?

Comment: You can't keep the auto_increment option if you change the type to VARCHAR.

Comment: @AaronBertrand The T is just to show that the ID belongs to a teacher. While A shows the person is an Admin. I have been told to do this

Comment: @Jocelyn I know, I mean if I get rid of the auto increment and somehow work out how to include the latest 'T '. So if T3 is highest T value, then next value inserted should be T4

Comment: The table name is `Teacher`, it is quite obvious it is used to store teacher data. Did you read Aaron's comment posted earlier? you can easily add the T when you display the data in your webpage.

Comment: @Jocelyn Is there a way on the webpage to include T for Teacher and A for Admin to seperate those that are teachers and those that are admins?

Comment: Just move your CONCAT above to the SELECT instead of trying to UPDATE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I highly recommend you consider appending the T to the *display* at query time instead of trying to store a T on every single row. I don't understand the purpose of storing the data this way, particularly if you have other tables that use the TeacherId value in its native form.

If you need to distinguish teachers from admins, then two thoughts:

1. The table should be called Personnel, not Teachers.
2. This can still be stored as a separate column e.g. PersonnelType.

I know you might have been told that it should show as T3 etc., but surely they did not tell you explicitly "we want you to store the T and 3 together in the same column, or else." You can show them T3 without shoehorning them together in a terrible and unusable design.

Answer (score 1):

To select the data and automatically add the letter T in front of TeacherId:

```
SELECT *, CONCAT('T', TeacherId) AS TeacherId2 FROM Teacher
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must have it in your table, create a second column in your table, so your create would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE  `teacher` (

`teacherId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`t` CHAR( 10 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
)
```

Then create a trigger to set your second column to 'T' concatenated with your id.

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER teacherInsert after INSERT ON teacher
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE teacher SET `t` = concat('T', teacherId);
  END;
|

delimiter ;
```

Alternatively, you can also do what Aaron suggests, and just get it at query time:

```
select teacherId, concat('T', teacherId) from teacher
```

Comment: Does MySQL have a concept of a computed/calculated column? In general, I think this would be easier to manage than a trigger. But in this specific case, I don't think it will work, because there is other information required to determine if the prefix should be `'T'` (for teacher) or `'A'` (for admin).